# Javascript setar valor de um campo em outros

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue() {
      var x = document.getElementById("NuJaneiro");

      document.getElementById("NuFevereiro").value = x.value;
    }
  </script>

 <td>
    <input type="text" style="width: 80px;" runat="server" id="NuJaneiro" value='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Janeiro"))%>'
      name="NuJaneiro" onblur="getValue()" />
  </td>


  <td>
    <input type="text" style="width: 80px;" runat="server" id="NuFevereiro" value='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Fevereiro"))%>'
      name="NuFevereiro" onblur="getValue()" />
  </td>
```

A minha ideia é pegar o valor de um campo e por em outro assim que o usuário sai do primeiro campo, porem, o valor não esta sendo passado e quando depuro pelo browser trava a tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não da nenhum erro?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, erro não esta dando mais o valor não esta sendo passado para o `<input type="text" style="width: 80px;" runat="server" id="NuFevereiro"`

Comment: Não, não faça isso. Apagar os comentários é apagar o histórico. Onde está a resposta que deu certo? No comentário do @Laerte, não vejo nenhum link para um fiddle ou algo parecido.

Comment: @pnet ele postou a resposta.

Comment: o comentário foi pelo comentário, mas depois que eu postei é que eu vi. Achei que ele tivesse postado um link para um fiddle ou etc e não estava aparecendo para mim. Mas valeu e sucesso aí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Web Forms o ID por padrão é gerado dinamicamente.

Altere a propriedade **ClientIDMode** para **Static** para isso não ocorrer e permanecer o ID que você definiu.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NuJaneiro" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: Nesse caso eu não posso definir como Static, mas, deu a ideia de como eu pegar o id renderizado.

Comment: É que não estou com VS aqui, mas se não me falha a memória o padrão é nomeForm:idElemento né?

Comment: `BodyContent_livCamposForm_NuJaneiro_4` . são vários campos criados pelo fato de esta dentro de um `ListView`